# Comprobar conexion ODBC en Centos 7 PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, odbc

Comunidad, estoy intentando realizar una conexión entre mi sitio web y una base de datos que esta en SQL, tengo entendido que es necesario configurar el ODBC Driver, actualmente mi sitio esta alojado en un servidor con CentOs 7 y la BD en un Windows Server, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php

// Configuration Settings for connection to Database
$host = 'IPPUBLICA\DB';
$user = 'web';
$pass = 'sasalalala';
$db   = 'DB';
$conn = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=$host;PORT=8888;DATABASE=$db";

// Open connection
$db_connect = odbc_connect($conn, $user, $pass);
?>
```

El problema es de que no logo determinar si en realidad estoy llegando a la base pues no me muestra en pantalla errores, existe alguna manera de comprobar si efectivamente se logra la conexion!

Les dejo parte de mi codigo PHP que ejecuta las consultas:

```
include 'conndb.php';
if ( isset( $_POST[ "submit" ] ) && !empty( $_POST[ "submit" ] ) ) {
  $codigo = $_POST[ "codigo" ];
  //echo "<b>" .$codigo . "</b>";
}
$alumnos = odbc_exec( $db_connect, "SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.producto WHERE icdbarra = '$codigo'" );
//odbc_result_all($alumnos);
if ( !$alumnos )
  die( "Error: no se ha podido realizarla consulta 1" );
while ( $fila = odbc_fetch_array( $alumnos ) ) {
  echo "NOMBRE: $fila[nproducto]<br>CODIGO: $fila[icdbarra]<br>PRODUCTO: $fila[producto]<br>";
  $producto = $fila[ "producto" ];
}
```

Comment: Dado que `odbc_connect()` devuelve `FALSE` en caso de error, puedes verificar el estado de la conexión con algo así, en el archivo de conexión o después del include: `if (!$db_connect) {  echo odbc_errormsg(); }  else { //hay conexión... usarla }` El uso aquí de `odbc_errormsg()` es sólo para saber el motivo del error en fase de depuración, en fase de producción deberías evitar mostrar errores internos, cambiándolos por mensajes personalizados.

Comment: Puedes ayudarme a colocar el código de manera correcta para que pueda visualizar el problema con el odbc_errormsg(); soy nuevo en esto.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que `odbc_connect()` devuelve `FALSE` en caso de error, puedes verificar el estado de la conexión antes de pasar a ejecutar consultas. Puedes hacerlo en el archivo de conexión o después del include.

Tu código podría quedar así, lo he organizado un poco mejor. Todavía faltaría aplicar consultas preparadas, pero ese es otro tema:

```
include 'conndb.php';

if (!$db_connect) {  
    die(odbc_errormsg()); 
}  else { 
    if ( isset( $_POST[ "submit" ] ) && !empty( $_POST[ "submit" ] ) ) {
        $codigo = $_POST[ "codigo" ];
        if ($alumnos = odbc_exec( $db_connect, "SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.producto WHERE icdbarra = '$codigo'" )) {
            while ( $fila = odbc_fetch_array( $alumnos ) ) {
                echo "NOMBRE: $fila[nproducto]<br>CODIGO: $fila[icdbarra]<br>PRODUCTO: $fila[producto]<br>";
                $producto = $fila[ "producto" ]; //???
            }
        } else {
            die( "Error: no se ha podido realizarla consulta 1" );
        }
    }
}
```

El uso aquí de `odbc_errormsg()` es sólo para saber el motivo del error en fase de depuración, en fase de producción deberías evitar mostrar errores internos, cambiándolos por mensajes personalizados.

Este código te dirá si la conexión funciona o no, y por qué motivo.